# Check whether $f(x)=x^5+10x^3+10x+3$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ or not.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $f(x)=x^5+10x^3+10x+3$ be a polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[i][x]$. We have to check whether it is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}(i)[x]$ or not.

As $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ is quotient field of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ and $f$ is primitive, $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[i][x]$ iff $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}(i)[x]$.

I am not able to apply Eisenstein Criterion here. Is there any way out to solve this kind of problems without explicitly finding the roots?

Can anyone give me any idea how to solve the problem? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: If an $a+bi$ were a root, then so would be $a-bi$ and $f$ would be divisible by $x^2-2ax+(a^2+b^2)$. However, $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, since $f(x+2)$ satisfies Eisenstein's criterion for $p=5$. Assuming that $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ is a factorization with degrees $2$ and $3$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $f^2=(g\overline{g})(h\overline{h})$ would be a factorization of $f^2$ into factors of degrees $4$ and $6$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Using again that $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, this is not possible.

Comment: More of a general strategy but here we go. Suppose we know that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$). Then, $K=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f)$ defines a degree five extension over the rationals. Suppose over $\mathbf{Q}[i]$, $f$ splits into multiple irreducible factors. We have some issues with the degree now. If $g(X)\in\mathbb{Q}[i](X)$ is an irreducible factor, we know $L=\mathbb{Q}[i](X)/(g)$ contains the subfield $K$. This is a problem as $[L:\mathbb{Q}(i)]<5$ if we assume $f$ splits.

Comment: @daruma I don't get the contraction.

Comment: $[L:\mathbb{Q}(i)]<5$ tells us that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ is not divisible by $5$ yet $L$ contains $K$ as a subfield which is a degree five extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, that I understand. But how to show that $L$ contains $K$.

Comment: @plop Thanks for your help. But Can you let me know how do you find Eisenstein would work on $f(x+2)$. I mean is there any way out to find such expressions like $f(x+2)$ or just trial and error?

Comment: The search can probably be done by an algorithm, since the coefficients of $f(x+a)$ are polynomials in $a$ and we are looking for primes such that they have a common root modulo that prime. Factorization over the integers [can also be done by and algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Factoring_univariate_polynomials_over_the_integers). In my case I really just tried $f(x+2)$ and it worked.

Comment: Need somebody to answer this question. It is being duplicated elsewhere on MSE but the program will not let me VTC that question as a dupe without an updated or accepted answer here.